# How to use variables in an R1C1 range in pivot table consolidation, excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can I get my new cells ref or Variables containing the row & Column number recognised as an actual eg. R38C8 reference for use by the consolidate function?

My two pivot tables rows and columns constantly change, I've got the new row and column number range - ready for a R1C1 ref but can't get the consolidate to work using a variable or cell reference in the formula - I'm new at this, just done a 3week crash course... Please help, it's driving me crazy!...

Last part of my code, trying a cells ref (consolidate doesn't like "& arS" or RarS:

```
RS = 32 + RowCountS
CS = ColCountS
RI = 63 + RowCountI
CI = ColCountI

arS = Cells(RS, CS)  ' Stock table, last cell in the range 
arI = Cells(RI, CI) 'Invoiced Table last cell in the range

' Creates a new table by consolidating the negative invoiced amounts with the stock movements totals
'
Sheets("Calculated Stock").Range("A4").Select

 Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array( _
    "'Calculated Stock'!R32C1:R" & arS"" _
    , _
    "'Calculated Stock'!R63C1:R" & arI"" _
    ), Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
 Range("A4").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
arS = Cells(RS, CS)
```

sets the variant arS to whatever value or text is held in the cell. I think that you think it holds a pointer to the cell - but that would require the line

```
       Set arS = cells(rs,cs)
```

You would have eliminated this error if you had Option Explicit set and had declared arS as a range with

```
     Dim arS as Range
```

With the code you have you would use

```
  "'Calculated Stock'!R32C1:R" & RS & "C" & CS
```

With arS set as a pointer you would use

```
 "'Calculated Stock'!R32C1:" & arS.address(true,true,xlR1C1)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I just didn't realise the difference between ars= , set ars= as well as the proper use of the address property(?)…. I can't thank you enough for helping me.... this site is just amazing, I've learned so much from it and people like you :)